# Stiefel Whitney number of a fiber bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, fibre-bundles, stiefel-whitney

I was going through this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199000024?via%3Dihub), and the author rights the following

> The Stiefel-Whitney class of $E$ is given by $$w(E)=(1+\alpha)^{2m+1}\left\{(1+c)^{2n+1}+u_1(1+c)^{2n}+\dots+u_{2n}(1+c)+u_{2n+1}\right\}$$ (see 1). From [5, Lemma 3.1] one has $$\alpha^{2m-i} c^{2n+i}[E]=\alpha^{2m-i} \overline u_i[\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2m}]$$

Where E is the total space of a fibre bundle over $2m-$dimensional projective space and fibre $2n $-dimensional projective space.

I am aware of the expression that he is writing for the SW class of E but I am not so sure about the Stiefel Whitney no. expression where he says that evaluation of monomials on the fundamental class of the total space is equal to the evaluation on the fundamental class of the base. How can that be true? The [reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-14/issue-3/The-bordism-class-of-a-bundle-space/10.1307/mmj/1028999779.full) that he gives is not answering my problem.

Thanks in advance

**Edit-1**
In the linked reference, I was able to find a relation on page no—294 between the fundamental class of the complex projectivization and the fundamental class of the base.

Will it help us to work out using the relation between Cup and cap products?

Any suggestions will be helpful.